# How to reference this id in py file

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

How can I reference `id: output` in the `main.py` file to print a message on the label ?

I tried

```
self.root.ids.screen_manager.get_screen("Caesar_Screen").ids.output.text =“”
```

but I always get this error

```
C:\Users\Samoo\PycharmProjects\CryptoMD2\venv\Scripts\python.exe 

C:\Users\Samoo\PycharmProjects\CryptoMD2\main.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Samoo\.kivy\logs\kivy_21-05-03_57.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.3.2
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\Samoo\PycharmProjects\CryptoMD2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:57:15) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\Samoo\PycharmProjects\CryptoMD2\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] v0.104.1
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.3.0 - Build 20.19.15.5126'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 3
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.30 - Build 20.19.15.5126'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
B
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 861, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 KeyError: 'screen_manager'
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Samoo\PycharmProjects\CryptoMD2\main.py", line 46, in <module>
     CryptoMD().run()
   File "C:\Users\Samoo\PycharmProjects\CryptoMD2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 950, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\Samoo\PycharmProjects\CryptoMD2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 582, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\Samoo\PycharmProjects\CryptoMD2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 347, in mainloop
     self.idle()
   File "C:\Users\Samoo\PycharmProjects\CryptoMD2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 391, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "C:\Users\Samoo\PycharmProjects\CryptoMD2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 342, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "C:\Users\Samoo\PycharmProjects\CryptoMD2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 248, in post_dispatch_input
     listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Samoo\PycharmProjects\CryptoMD2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1412, in on_motion
     self.dispatch('on_touch_down', me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Samoo\PycharmProjects\CryptoMD2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1428, in on_touch_down
     if w.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Samoo\PycharmProjects\CryptoMD2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 1198, in on_touch_down
     return super(ScreenManager, self).on_touch_down(touch)
   File "C:\Users\Samoo\PycharmProjects\CryptoMD2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 545, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Samoo\PycharmProjects\CryptoMD2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\relativelayout.py", line 297, in on_touch_down
     ret = super(RelativeLayout, self).on_touch_down(touch)
   File "C:\Users\Samoo\PycharmProjects\CryptoMD2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 545, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Samoo\PycharmProjects\CryptoMD2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 545, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Samoo\PycharmProjects\CryptoMD2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 545, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Samoo\PycharmProjects\CryptoMD2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 138, in on_touch_down
     if super(ButtonBehavior, self).on_touch_down(touch):
   File "C:\Users\Samoo\PycharmProjects\CryptoMD2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 545, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Samoo\PycharmProjects\CryptoMD2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 545, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Samoo\PycharmProjects\CryptoMD2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\behaviors\ripplebehavior.py", line 231, in on_touch_down
     return super().on_touch_down(touch)
   File "C:\Users\Samoo\PycharmProjects\CryptoMD2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\button.py", line 961, in on_touch_down
     return super().on_touch_down(touch)
   File "C:\Users\Samoo\PycharmProjects\CryptoMD2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 151, in on_touch_down
     self.dispatch('on_press')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 705, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1248, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1132, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Samoo\PycharmProjects\CryptoMD2\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 57, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "C:\Users\Samoo\PycharmProjects\CryptoMD2\cryptomd.kv", line 100, in <module>
     app.out_encrypt(Text.text, key.text) if key.text != "" else None
   File "C:\Users\Samoo\PycharmProjects\CryptoMD2\main.py", line 34, in out_encrypt
     self.root.ids.screen_manager.get_screen("Caesar_Screen").ids.output.text = out_encrypted
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 864, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

in the terminal where it says [INFO  ]..
the letter B before Leaving the application is the message I want to display on the Label. the the error message starts with

```
 KeyError: 'screen_manager'
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
# from funcs import Encrypt
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase


class Caesar_Screen(Screen):
    pass


class Aes_Screen(Screen):
    pass


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Caesar_Screen(name='Caesar'))
sm.add_widget(Aes_Screen(name='Aes'))


class CryptoMD(MDApp):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.Encrypt = Encrypt()
        self.title = 'Crypto'
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Purple"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def out_encrypt(self, Text, key):
        obj = Encrypt()
        Text = Text.lower()
        key = key
        Key = int(key)
        out_encrypted = obj.encrypt(Text, key)
        self.root.ids.screen_manager.get_screen("Caesar_Screen").ids.output.text = out_encrypted

    def out_decrypt(self, Text, key):
        obj = Encrypt()
        Text = Text.lower()
        key = key
        Key = int(key)
        out_decrypted = obj.decrypt(Text, key)
        self.root.ids.screen_manager.get_screen("Caesar_Screen").ids.output.text = out_encrypted


class Encrypt():
    def encrypt(self, Text, key):
        Text = Text.lower()
        key = key
        Key = int(key)
        encrypted_message = ""

        for c in Text:
            if c in alphabet:
                position = alphabet.find(c)
                new_position = (position + Key) % 26
                new_character = alphabet[new_position]
                encrypted_message += new_character
            else:
                encrypted_message += c
        message = str(encrypted_message)
        print(message.upper())
        return message.upper()

    def decrypt(self, Text, key):
        Text = Text.lower()
        key = key
        Key = int(key)
        encrypted_message = ""

        for c in Text:
            if c in alphabet:
                position = alphabet.find(c)
                new_position = (position - Key) % 26
                new_character = alphabet[new_position]
                encrypted_message += new_character
            else:
                encrypted_message += c
        message = str(encrypted_message)
        print(message.upper())
        return message.upper()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CryptoMD().run()
```

```
#:kivy 1.11.1
#:import rgba kivy.utils.rgba

ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager

    Caesar_Screen:
    Aes_Screen:

<Caesar_Screen>:
    name: "Caesar_Screen"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        BoxLayout:
            id: bx
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint_y: 0.2
            padding: [20, 10, 10, 20]
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: rgba('#8A2BE2')
                RoundedRectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
                    radius: [0, 0, 90, 90]


        BoxLayout:
            MDCard:
                id: card
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: [0.35, 1]
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.65}
                padding: [30, 10, 25, 10]
                spacing: 7

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'horizontal'
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "[color=000000] Caesar Cipher [/color]"
                        text_size: self.size
                        font_size: 28
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        halign: "left"
                        valign: "top"

                    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                        text: 'AES'
                        size: self.size
                        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.9, 'center_y': 0.77}
                        on_press: root.manager.current = 'Aes_Screen'

                MDLabel:
                    id: output
                    text: "[color=000000] Output [/color]"
                    text_size: self.size
                    font_size: 27
                    bold: False
                    markup: True
                    halign: "center"
                    valign: "top"

                BoxLayout:
                    padding: [0, 0, 50, 0]
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    MDTextField:
                        id: Text
                        text: "a"
                        auto_indent: True
                        allow_copy: True
                        multiline: False
                        helper_text: "Enter Text..."
                        helper_text_mode: "persistent"
                        max_text_length: 100
                        required: True
                        allow_copy: True

                    MDTextField:
                        id: key
                        text: "1"
                        input_filter: "int"
                        helper_text: "Enter Key..."
                        helper_text_mode: "persistent"
                        required: True
                        allow_copy: True
                BoxLayout:
                    padding: [0, 0, 0, 0]
                    spacing: 3
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    MDRoundFlatButton:
                        id: encrypt_bt
                        text: "Encrypt"
                        size: self.size
                        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
                        on_press:
                            app.out_encrypt(Text.text, key.text) if key.text != "" else None

                    MDRoundFlatButton:
                        id: decrypt_bt
                        text: "Decrypt"
                        size: self.size
                        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
                        on_press:
                            app.out_decrypt(Text.text, key.text) if key.text != "" else None

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            padding: [30, 10, 30, 20]
            spacing: 20
            size_hint_y: 0.25
            pos: self.pos


            Widget:
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: rgba('#bfff00')
                    Ellipse:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
            Widget:
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: rgba('#8A2BE2')
                    Ellipse:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
            Widget:

                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: rgba('#00ffff')
                    Ellipse:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size


<Aes_Screen>:
    name: "Aes_Screen"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: What class contains the line: `self.root.ids.screen_manager.get_screen("Caesar_Screen").ids.output.text = out_encrypted`?

Comment: show more code. In which place do you run it? As I remeber Kivy classse may load `kv` after running `__init___` so code in `__init__` may not work - and it may need to use scheduler to run code with small delay.

Comment: @JohnAnderson this one `class CryptoMD(MDApp):`

Comment: @furas I use Pycharm on windows 10 , full code is now included, can u check again please.

Comment: works for me: `self.root.get_screen("Caesar_Screen").ids.output.text` without `.ids.screen_manager`

Comment: BTW: code works also without `sm = ScreenManager()` and `sm.add_widget(...)` because it creates second screen manager which is never used. And if I use `sm.get_screen("Caesar_Screen").ids` then I get empty `{}`

Comment: @furas uhh now I see ! Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, sometimes I don't understand why `ids` works or not.

In your code works

```
 self.root.get_screen("Caesar_Screen").ids.output.text
```

without `.ids.screen_manager`

---

**BTW:**

You don't need `sm = ScreenManager()` and `sm.add_widget(...)` because it creates second screen manager which is never used. And if I use `sm.get_screen("Caesar_Screen").ids` then I gives empty `{}`

If you created `self.Encrypt = Encrypt()` then you don't have to create `obj = Encrypt()` - you can use `self.Encrypt.encrypt(Text, key)` instead of `obj.encrypt(Text, key)`

There is other suggestion: use `lower_case_names` for variables (ie. `self.encrypt` isntead of `self.Encrypt` or `text` instead of `Text`) and `CamelCaseNames` only for classes because it helps to recognize classes in code. Some IDEs may even use special color for `CamelCaseNames` to even simpler recognize classes in code.

See more in [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Functions `encrypt` and `decrypt` are almost the same - the only difference is `+key` and `-key` - so you could create one function and run it with `+key` or `-key`

---

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase


class Caesar_Screen(Screen):
    pass

class Aes_Screen(Screen):
    pass


class CryptoMD(MDApp):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.encrypt = Encrypt()   # PEP8: `CamelCaseNames` for classes, but `loser_case_names` for variables
        self.title = 'Crypto'
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Purple"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def out_encrypt(self, text, key):
        out_encrypted = self.encrypt.encrypt(text, key)
        self.root.get_screen("Caesar_Screen").ids.output.text = out_encrypted
 
    def out_decrypt(self, text, key):
        out_encrypted = self.encrypt.decrypt(text, key)
        self.root.get_screen("Caesar_Screen").ids.output.text = out_encrypted


class Encrypt():

    def encrypt(self, text, key):
        return self.convert(text,  int(key))

    def decrypt(self, text, key):  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables
        return self.convert(text, -int(key))

    def convert(self, text, key):
        text = text.lower()
        key = int(key)
        
        encrypted_message = ""

        for char in text:
            if char in alphabet:
                position = alphabet.find(char)
                new_position = (position + key) % 26
                new_character = alphabet[new_position]
                encrypted_message += new_character
            else:
                encrypted_message += char

        print(encrypted_message.upper())
        
        return encrypted_message.upper()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CryptoMD().run()
```